# How to Kill sessions running for last 5 minutes automatically in azure analysis services?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-analysis-services

I have a requirement to kill the active sessions currently running on Azure Analysis Services which are consuming high QPU and are running for more than 5 minutes.

I came across below article : which does similar thing and it's a manual process but I need help in understanding how can I setup an automated process which can proactively identify and kill such connections.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/disconnect-users-and-sessions-on-analysis-services-server?view=asallproducts-allversions

Appreciate any leads.

Comment: Does log analytics query works for you? @Learn2Code

Answer (score 0):

> How to Kill sessions running for last 5 minutes automatically in azure analysis services?

To make it work automatically, you can use either PowerShell or log analytics Kql query which is detailed below.

[Disconnect sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/desktopvirtualization/user-sessions/disconnect?view=rest-desktopvirtualization-2022-02-10-preview&tabs=HTTP) MS Doc.

*PowerShell:*

```
$subscription = "xxx"
$resourceGroup = "xxxx"
$serverName = "asazure://eastus.asazure.windows.net/newsj"
$uri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscription/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/$serverName/sessions/$sessionId/disconnect?api-version=2017-07-14"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}
```

[image]

*KQL: (Log analytics workspace)*

Sample query for your requirement looks like below:

```bash
AzureMetrics
| where Resource == "newsj"
| where MetricName == "xxx"
| summarize startat = min(TimeGenerated), timespan = max(xxx) by resourceID
```

Comment: Thanks, I think log analytics can help in fetching the queries which are long running but I don't think it can cancel the session too..?

Comment: Yes sometimes. In that case you can go with the PowerShell approach. Have you tried that? @Learn2Code